# Pair them Down - Algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Input an even integer `N`, then an array `A` of size `N`. Partition the array into `N/2` pairs so that the sum of squares `(A[i] + A[j])^2` is minimum.

Example:

```
Input  
4  
2 1 2 2

Output
25
```

What I was doing is:

- sorting the array
- iterating from start till middle
- ans = ans + square of (A[i]+A[n-1-i])

And I just got 37.5% answer correct. I think that I have done it correct. I don't know what testcases am I failing. Help!

```cpp
int main(){
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin >> n;

        vi nums(n);
        rep(i,0,n-1){
            cin >> nums[i]; 
        }

        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

        int totalSum = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++){
            int sum = (nums[i]+nums[n-1-i])*(nums[i]+nums[n-1-i]);
            totalSum += sum;
    }

    cout << totalSum << endl;
}
```

Comment: Intuitively, I think your algorithm should be correct. Could you please edit your question to add your exact code?

Comment: Where are the associated macros?

Comment: Please edit the code you've shown us to make it a [mre]: include the definition of `vi`, `rep`, and all relevant `include` and `using`.